# How to make an open bezier curve?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, bezier-curve

I'm drawing an exemplary function graph using bezier curve:

[image: Graph]

Notice the horizontal line which appears because of automatic closure, merge of the first and last vertices. How can I disable this behaviour? I don't need a shape, nor color filling, nor closing, just an open bezier path.

Comment: You should probably be using illustrator.

Comment: @joojaa you mean such a simple thing is't possible in photoshop? :(

Comment: Do realise that Photoshop is not the One App to Rule and Bind them. It is, at its core, an app to manipulate and create *pixel* images. It has some vector capabilities, but those are limited because Illustrator is there to do them better.

Comment: Thanks for sarcasm guys, I've got it `:]` Ok, I installed Illustartor, exported my curve there, how can I un-close my path there?

Comment: Select edge and hit delete

Comment: @joojaa using which tool? The "Selection tool" selected whole vector object as I can see, and the "Direct selection tool" selects vertices, I see nothing helping to select edges

Comment: If you click with direct selection tool on a edge it has selected that edge even if it does not give you any feedback

Comment: Technically there is feedback its just hard to see untill you know what your looking for. The tangents are visible for selected edges. But its unlikely your shape has tangents. But since vector drawing is modeling, and you do much of the model reasoning in your head you would know what is where anyway. Eventually.

Comment: @joojaa I found no way to disable automatic path closure of a curve exported from PhSh, but I'v successfully created opened curve that I needed. I guess that that closure isn't a selectable edge, cuz I'm able to delete any edge of a curve native created in Illusstator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119415/discussion-between-joojaa-and-aivanf).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with others that vector drawing quickly gets too limited in Photoshop and that Illustrator is a better alternative.

But I can't reproduce the problem. In Photoshop 2020 I can draw Bezier curves which are not closed. And if they are closed I can select an edge with *Direct Selection Tool* and delete it.

[image]

Edit: Perhaps your problem lies in drawing a *Path* instead of a *Shape*. While having the *Pen Tool* selected, in the top tool bar try selecting *Shape* instead of *Path*.

[image]